# React - Set input number value conditionally

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 input type number fields and I'm trying to set the second field value(num2) conditionally based on the first one's(num1) value.

```
<input ref="num1" type="number" min="1" max="7" defaultValue={6}/>

<input ref="num2" type="number" min="0" max={this.refs.num1 === 7 ? 0 : 10} defaultValue={10}/>
```

I've tried the above ternary operator to set value 0 if `num1`'s value is equal to 7. The default value for `num1` is 6 and when I stepup to 7, there is no different I can see in `num2`.

Please help me fix this.

Comment: For detailed investigation you have to investigate this beautifully explained documentation(masterpiece) -> https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 1):

Try validating by using onChange event in the input

```
<input onChange={this.onChange} />
```

And create a method `onChange` with womthing like:

```
onChange(e) {
   let value = e.target.value;
   return validation;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I understand what you want, but you can try something like this :

```
class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        num1: null
      }
    }

    onChange(num, e){       
        this.setState({num1: e.target.value});
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <input type="number" min="1" max="7" defaultValue={6} value={this.state.num1} onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, "num1")}/>
                <input type="number" min="0" max={10} value={this.state.num1 == 7 ? 10 : 0} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

React.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Add state to your component and then change the value of the first input via an onChange function.

Then depending on that value show value of the second input.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1410/).

Comment: Theywant to dynamically set the maxattribute, not the value.

Comment: @Pureferret  **I'm trying to set the second field value(num2)** That is in the question.